# How to have content shown next to a table with hidden rows excel

Tags: excel, formatting

I have a table with dropdowns that will hide certain rows. To the right of this table, I want to have some content, but can't do this as it will be hidden when these dropdowns are selected. I currently have the content to the bottom right of the sheet and have tried splitting the screen to have them both showing but this does not work either. Any ideas on how I can have the two showing side by side? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten around this by using Text Boxes. After creating the text box, change the properties to "do not move or size".

In the picture below, there are two text boxes.

-- The first one is just static text that you copy/paste in there. This works fine as long as you have the same info displayed all the time.

-- The second one has the ability to be somewhat dynamic, where it references the contents of another cell. That cell can be anywhere (this sheet, another sheet, doesn't matter). So in this example...

```
Cell L1 formula: =TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), TRUE,E1:E3)

Textbox formula: =Sheet4!L1
```

No matter how you filter/hide, those text boxes won't move.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The only problem is that the content I have has conditional formatting (many of the cells have changing colours). Is there a way to maintain this formatting?